# fabsdk/util configure MSP failed: sanitizeCert failed the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

When I run fabric-sdk-go code in the fabric network,some certificate problem happened to me.

Firstly, when i create the fabric sdk client, I got a warnning:

```bash
 [fabsdk/util] 2023/02/20 13:04:42 UTC - lazyref.(*Reference).refreshValue -> WARN Error - initializer returned error: load MSPs from config failed: configure MSP failed: sanitizeCert failed the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority. Will retry again later
```

and then when i tried to invoke the chaincode, it came to an error:

```bash
invoke chaincode error: signature validation failed: Endorser Client Status Code: (8) SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILED. Description: the creator certificate is not valid
```

The invoke command works well in the fabric-cli container,so it confuse me.I checkout the fabric sdk's config file,and find nothing wrong compared with fabric-sdk-go's test config file.

fabric version:2.2.9.And i got 2 orgs and each org had 2 peers.

here is my fabric-sdk config file

```yaml
name: "example-network"
#
# Schema version of the content. Used by the SDK to apply the corresponding parsing rules.
#
version: 1.0.0

#
# The client section used by GO SDK.
#
client:

  organization: Org1

  logging:
    level: info

    peer:
      timeout:
        connection: 10s
        response: 180s
        discovery:
          greylistExpiry: 10s
        registrationResponse: 10s
    orderer:
      timeout:
        connection: 3s
        response: 10s
    global:
      timeout:
        query: 45s
        execute: 60s
        resmgmt: 60s
      cache: 
        connectionIdle: 30s
        eventServiceIdle: 2m
        channelConfig: 60s
        channelMembership: 30s

  cryptoconfig:
    path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config

  credentialStore:
    path: "/tmp/example-store"
    cryptoStore:
      path: /tmp/example-msp

    # BCCSP config for the client. Used by GO SDK.
  BCCSP:
    security:
      enabled: true
      default:
        provider: "SW"
      hashAlgorithm: "SHA2"
      softVerify: true
      level: 256

  tlsCerts:
    # [Optional]. Use system certificate pool when connecting to peers, orderers (for negotiating TLS) Default: false
    systemCertPool: false

    # [Optional]. Client key and cert for TLS handshake with peers and orderers
    client:
      key:
        path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.root.example.com/users/User1@org1.root.example.com/tls/client.key
      cert:
        path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.root.example.com/users/User1@org1.root.example.com/tls/client.crt


channels:
  # name of the channel
  mychannel:
    peers:
      peer0.org1.root.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer1.org1.root.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer0.org2.root.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
        
      peer1.org2.root.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
        

    policies:
      queryChannelConfig:
        minResponses: 1
        maxTargets: 1
        retryOpts:
          attempts: 5
          initialBackoff: 500ms
          maxBackoff: 5s
          backoffFactor: 2.0
      discovery:
        maxTargets: 2
        retryOpts:
          attempts: 4
          initialBackoff: 500ms
          maxBackoff: 5s
          backoffFactor: 2.0
      eventService:
        resolverStrategy: PreferOrg
        balancer: Random
        blockHeightLagThreshold: 5
        reconnectBlockHeightLagThreshold: 10
        peerMonitorPeriod: 5s

organizations:
  Org1:
    mspid: Org1MSP
    cryptoPath: peerOrganizations/org1.root.example.com/users/{userName}@org1.root.example.com/msp
    peers:
      - peer0.org1.root.example.com
      - peer1.org1.root.example.com

    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca.org1.root.example.com

  Org2:
    mspid: Org2MSP
    cryptoPath: peerOrganizations/org2.root.example.com/users/{userName}@org2.root.example.com/msp
    peers:
      - peer0.org2.root.example.com
      - peer1.org2.root.example.com
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca.org2.root.example.com
  
  # Orderer Org name
  ordererorg:
      # Membership Service Provider ID for this organization
    mspID: OrdererMSP

      # Needed to load users crypto keys and certs for this org (absolute path or relative to global crypto path, DEV mode)
    cryptoPath: ordererOrganizations/root.example.com/users/Admin@root.example.com/msp


orderers:
  orderer.root.example.com:
    url: localhost:7050

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.root.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/root.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.root.example.com-cert.pem

peers:
  peer0.org1.root.example.com:
    url: localhost:7051
    eventUrl: localhost:7053

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.root.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.root.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.root.example.com-cert.pem

  peer1.org1.root.example.com:
    url: localhost:8051
    eventUrl: localhost:8053

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.org1.root.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.root.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.root.example.com-cert.pem

  peer0.org2.root.example.com:
    url: localhost:9051
    eventUrl: localhost:9053

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org2.root.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.root.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org2.root.example.com-cert.pem

  peer1.org2.root.example.com:
    url: localhost:10051
    eventUrl: localhost:10053

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.org2.root.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.root.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org2.root.example.com-cert.pem

certificateAuthorities:
  ca.org1.root.example.com:
    url: http://localhost:7054
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.root.example.com/ca/ca.org1.root.example.com-cert.pem
      client:
        key:
          path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.root.example.com/users/User1@org1.root.example.com/tls/client.key
        cert:
          path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.root.example.com/users/User1@org1.root.example.com/tls/client.crt
    registrar:
      enrollId: admin
      enrollSecret: adminpw
    caName: ca.org1.root.example.com

  ca.org2.root.example.com:
    url: http://localhost:8054
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.root.example.com/ca/ca.org2.root.example.com-cert.pem
      client:
        key:
          path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.root.example.com/users/User1@org2.root.example.com/tls/client.key
        cert:
          path: ${GOPATH}/src/test-network/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.root.example.com/users/User1@org2.root.example.com/tls/client.crt
    registrar:
      enrollId: admin
      enrollSecret: adminpw
    caName: ca.org2.root.example.com

entityMatchers:
  peer:
    - pattern: (\w*)peer0.org1.root.example.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7051
      eventUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7053
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer0.org1.root.example.com
      mappedHost: peer0.org1.root.example.com

    - pattern: (\w*)peer1.org1.root.example.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:8051
      eventUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost:8053
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer1.org1.root.example.com
      mappedHost: peer1.org1.root.example.com

    - pattern: (\w*)peer0.org2.root.example.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:9051
      eventUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost:9053
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer0.org2.root.example.com
      mappedHost: peer0.org2.root.example.com

    - pattern: (\w*)peer1.org2.root.example.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:10051
      eventUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost:10053
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer1.org2.root.example.com
      mappedHost: peer1.org2.root.example.com  

  orderer:
    - pattern: (\w*)orderer.root.example.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7050
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: orderer.root.example.com
      mappedHost: orderer.root.example.com

  certificateAuthorities:
    - pattern: (\w*)ca.org1.root.example.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: http://localhost:7054
      mappedHost: ca.org1.root.example.com

    - pattern: (\w*)ca.org2.root.example.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: http://localhost:8054
      mappedHost: ca.org2.root.example.com
```

And the error code and debug info:

```golang
    req := channel.Request{
        ChaincodeID: request.ChaincodeID,  //businessCC
        Fcn:         request.Fcn,          //modifyInfo
        Args:        request.Args,         //https://172.60.65.49:9001/chain/
    }
    reqPeers := channel.WithTargetEndpoints(c.PeerList...) //github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/channel.WithTargetEndpoints.func1
    resp, err := c.cc.Execute(req, reqPeers) //
```

I'm not sure the error was caused by the warrning,and i can't solve the MSP's certificate problem after i checked the network's configuration.Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try lowering the go version to 1.18, I solved the problem this way.